# If the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$ are equal, why are the corresponding coefficients of $\lambda^{n-1}$ equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem:** Similar matrices have the same trace.
>
> **Proof:** Let $A$ and $B$ be similar matrices. Then there is $P$, such that $B = P^{-1}AP$. Given that we have similar matrices then we also have the same characteristic polynomial, i.e $\phi(A, \lambda) = \phi(B, \lambda)$. Then the coefficients of $\lambda^{n-1}$ in $\phi(A, \lambda)$ is equal to the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ in $\phi(B, \lambda)$.

Please, can someone explain the last line? I do not understand which are the coefficients of $\lambda^{n-1}$ we are talking about.

Thank-you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is that the polynomials $\phi(A, \lambda)$ and $\phi(B, \lambda)$ are equal. Two polynomials are equal if and only if all of their coefficients are equal. As $\phi(A, \lambda)$ and $\phi(B, \lambda)$ are polynomials in $\lambda$, they both have a coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$. As $\phi(A, \lambda)$ and $\phi(B, \lambda)$ are equal, these coefficients are equal.

More symbolically, if $\phi(A, \lambda) = \lambda^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \dots + a_1\lambda + a_0$ and $\phi(B, \lambda) = \lambda^n + b_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \dots + b_1\lambda + b_0$, then the equality $\phi(A, \lambda) = \phi(B, \lambda)$ implies $a_i = b_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, n - 1$; in particular, $a_{n-1} = b_{n-1}$.